# How to set Thread specific breakpoints in Xcode?

Tags: iphone, multithreading, cocoa-touch, xcode, breakpoints

I'm debugging a crash where a non-main thread uses UIKit drawing methods. I'd like to set a conditional breakpoint on `-[UIView layoutSubviews]` that only triggers, if it's executed in a non-main thread. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set per-thread breakpoints using the gdb console. For example:

```
b -[UIView layoutSubviews] thread 2
```

(You use the gdb "info threads" commands to see what threads exist and what identifier gdb uses for them).

I don't think there's a way to set a breakpoint for every thread *except* the main thread (thread 1), but if you have a reasonable number of threads you could set breakpoints for each of them individually if necessary.

---

update:

If the per-thread thing isn't working out because of GCD, another approach you could take would be to just set a regular breakpoint, and set gdb commands for that breakpoint to dump out a backtrace ("where") and then "continue".

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Two questions: Is it normal that execution speed slows down considerably, up to a complete still stand? I've created breakpoints on `-layoutSubviews` as you suggested for all my running threads, none of them triggered yet. Secondly, is it correct that I can't set breakpoints for threads that don't exist yet? Which would make it pretty useless in the case of GCD where threads are spawned and ended regularly.

Comment: Good question. I don't know, but I would suspect that the per-thread breakpoint mechanism works by setting a regular breakpoint and then having gdb test the current thread id (and silently continuing if it's not the correct thread); I can see how that would get expensive. I don't know a way to set breakpoints for threads that don't exist.

Comment: Thanks, your answer was helpful nevertheless. I observed though that Xcode doesn't play well with those breakpoints. At the next launch of the app it adds these breakpoints again but without honoring the thread parameter. So the breakpoints end up being active for all threads. Nevertheless, it's better than nothing for finding those nasty UIKit calls on non-mainthread bugs.

Comment: Looks like this doesn't work with lldb any more. Does someone know the break command syntax for it?

Answer (score 1):

There is [a very useful bit of code](https://gist.github.com/steipete/5664345) that accomplishes exactly what you are asking. It's also much faster than using breakpoints. It does this by method swizzling a few UIKit methods (setNeedsLayout, setNeedsDisplay, etc.) and throwing an assertion if any are called on a thread other than the main thread.

It works great for catching these types of flaws during development, but be sure to remember to remove it from production code. It's also trivial to adapt to AppKit if need be.